# Issue decoding Ã¥ to correct letter å. Replacement for decodeURI(escape(string))?

Tags: javascript, decoding

result from a authentication call returns my name as Terje NygÃ¥rd, where Ã¥ should have been a Å.

I've solved it, using decodeUri and escape (depricated) like this

```
$rootScope.userInfo.userName = decodeURI(escape($rootScope.userInfo.userName));
```

Trying to find a replacement doing the same, but all other scenarios i've tried fails.

Could have lived with this solution, but it throws the error :

[image]

Anyone got a solution or replacement for this ?

Comment: You should address the underlying problem of a page being set up with the wrong character encoding.

Comment: @Pointy agreed, but the page(s) are setup with correct encoding.. It's this single scenario from angular-msal which does this "magic". All other norwegian chars like æøå works throughout the whole solution.

Comment: well if the encoding were correctly declared there would not be a problem. You can check this with browser tools.

Comment: document.characterSet displays UTF-8

Comment: OK, fine, but here's the obvious fact: **something** is interpreting a byte sequence in the wrong character set. The server, the browser, *something*. "Translating" the wrong stuff into the right stuff might work, but the real solution is to figure out what link in the chain is doing the wrong thing.